# How to create Network of websites with separate database in WordPress

Tags: multisite

I have 3 websites in WordPress with different databases and themes. For example:

- `www.example.com`,
- `www.example2.com`,
- `www.example3.com`

Now I want to create multinetwork of sites, means:

- `www.example.com/example2`, and
- `www.example.com/example3`.

So please tell me how is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multisite network in your wordpress. You can fellow these steps to create your network. 
[Create a network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

you can create as many sites as you want in your network.
although it uses 1 database for all sites, but every site has their own tables, you can differentiate every site tables very easily.

Comment: i want to make network of sites with separate database.
All site have Their own database.How it possible?